# why this limit is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_{n}=\frac{2a}{a+2}$

Tags: limits

Define sequence $a_{0}=\dfrac{a}{n},a>0$ and $$a_{i+1}=\ln{(1+a_{i})},i\ge 0$$

why this limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(na_{n})$$ is equal to $$=\dfrac{2a}{a+2}$$

Comment: is it really $a_0=\frac{a}{n}$?

Comment: yes,   It's real!

Comment: And what is $n$ in that?

Comment: if $a_{0}=\rm{constant}$ I can prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_{n}=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ADD it Solution 1:**

since
$$\dfrac{2x}{2+x}\le \ln{(1+x)}\le\dfrac{2x}{2+x-x^2},0\le x\le 1$$
then we have
$$a_{i+1}=\ln{(1+a_{i})}\ge\dfrac{2a_{i}}{2+a_{i}}$$
$$\Longrightarrow  \dfrac{1}{a_{i+1}}\le\dfrac{1}{a_{i}}+\dfrac{1}{2}$$
then we have
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}\le\dfrac{n}{2}+\dfrac{1}{a_{0}}=\dfrac{n(a+2)}{2a}\tag{1}$$

other hand
$$a_{i+1}\le\dfrac{2a_{i}}{2+a_{i}-a^2_{i}}\Longrightarrow \dfrac{1}{a_{i+1}}
\ge\dfrac{1}{a_{i}}+\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{a_{i}}{2}\ge\dfrac{1}{a_{i}}+\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{a_{0}}{2}$$
then we have
$$na_{n}\le\dfrac{2a}{a+2-\dfrac{a^2}{n}}\tag{2}$$
use $(1),(2)$ we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}na_{n}=\dfrac{2a}{a+2}$$

**Solution 2:**

it is easy to prove $a_{n}\to 0,n\to +\infty$

and $$a_{i+1}=a_{i}-\dfrac{a^2_{i}}{2}+o(a^2_{i})=a_{i}[1-\dfrac{a_{i}}{2}+o(a_{i})]$$
so 
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{i+1}}=\dfrac{1}{a_{i}[1-\dfrac{a_{i}}{2}+o(a_{i})]}=\dfrac{1}{a_{i}}+\dfrac{1}{2}+o(a_{i})$$
then we have
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}-\dfrac{1}{a_{0}}=\dfrac{n}{2}+o(a_{i})$$
so
$$a_{n}\approx \dfrac{1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{2a}{a+2},n\to+\infty$$

Comment: Two problems with this approach: 1. Both $o(a_i)$ should be $o(1)$. 2. To use this for some varying values of $a_0$, one needs some control on the error term.

Comment: I have edit it,